# How to import logsumexp from keras.backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-import

To be able to use `logsumexp` in the `keras.backend`, what is the appropriate way to import `Keras 2`?

Here is what I have tried and failed in colab. Both get `AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'logsumexp'`

- **1st round:**

```py
    import tensorflow
    import keras
    import keras.backend as K

    K.logsumexp
    keras.__version__ # 2.15.0
    tensorflow.__version__ #2.15.0
```

- **2nd round with a new session**

```py
    import tensorflow
    from tensorflow import keras
    from keras import backend as K

    K.logsumexp
    tensorflow.__version__ #2.15.0
```

I doubt the reason is that `logsumexp` is [not decorated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.15.0/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L2536) as others in `keras.backends`.

```
@keras_export('keras.backend.logsumexp')
@dispatch.add_dispatch_support
```